# Why were you not Moses?’ They’ll ask me, ‘Why were you not Zusya?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, story-identification

The story and final quote “Before his death, Rabbi Zusya said, ‘In the coming world, they will not ask me: Why were you not Moses?’ They will ask me: ‘Why were you not Zusya?’ ” is often ascribed to "the Talmud."

What's the actual reference?

Comment: Martin Buber, Tales of the Hasidim, Book I, p. 251.  Based on real story: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zusha_of_Hanipol

Comment: Zusha of Hanipol did not live in the times of Hazal. He is a Hasidic figure who lived in 18th century Poland.

Comment: Famously, the brother of Rav Elimelech of Lizhensk

Comment: It's most certainly not from the Talmud and this is the first I've come across anyone claiming such

Comment: Can you point to a source that ascribes it to the Talmud?